# Finding the maximum of a function

Tags: python, numpy

How do I find the maximum of a function in Python?  I could try to hack together a derivative function and find the zero of that, but is there a method in `numpy` (or other library) that can do it for me?

Comment: Look into golden section search.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search

Comment: @EMS that's generally what I do, but I'm not always on SO.  You gotta give people some time :P

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.optimize.fmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) on the negative of your function.

```
def f(x): return -2 * x**2 + 4 * x
max_x = scipy.optimize.fmin(lambda x: -f(x), 0)
# array([ 1.])
```

Comment: But please note, that you really need to pay attention to numerical analysis issues here. It's often a red flag of impending error when someone says "how can a library solve this for me?" Make sure that *you* really understand what the library function is doing. That's true even if you've been doing numerical work for a long time. I recently suffered a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038543/tracking-down-the-assumptions-made-by-scipys-ttest-ind-function) with `scipy.stats`.

Comment: I am sorry for unrelated question, but why there is zero in lambda expression?

Comment: The zero is not a part of the `lambda`. A `lambda` cannot implicitly return a `tuple` by returning a comma-separated sequence of values, the way that a regular Python function can. In this case, the comma is part of the argument list to `scipy.optimize.fmin`, so the entire first argument is `lambda x: -f(x)` and the entire second argument is `0`.

Comment: To see this, you can try to define a `lambda` that returns a `tuple` in the comma-separated manner. Try something like: `f = lambda x: x,x+1` and (unless `x` is defined elsewhere) you should get an error `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` because the `x+1` part is not part of the `lambda`.

Comment: Ah, I see, zero is initial guess for fmin. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

If your function is solvable analytically try SymPy. I'll use EMS's example above.

```
In [1]: from sympy import *
In [2]: x = Symbol('x', real=True)

In [3]: f = -2 * x**2 + 4*x

In [4]: fprime = f.diff(x)
In [5]: fprime
Out[5]: -4*x + 4

In [6]: solve(fprime, x) # solve fprime = 0 with respect to x
Out[6]: [1]
```

Of course, you'll still need to check that 1 is a maximizer and not a minimizer of f

```
In [7]: f.diff(x).diff(x) < 0
Out[7]: True
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar` and `scipy.optimize.minimize` are the preferred ways now, that give you access to the range of techniques, e.g.

```
solution = scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar(lambda x: -f(x), bounds=[0,1], method='bounded')
```

for a single variable function that must lie between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html).  SymPy might be able to provide you with the derivative symbolically, find its zeros, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Maximum of a function with parameters.

```
import scipy.optimize as opt

def get_function_max(f, *args):
    """
    >>> round(get_function_max(lambda x, *a: 3.0-2.0*(x**2)), 2)
    3.0

    >>> round(get_function_max(lambda x, *a: 3.0-2.0*(x**2)-2.0*x), 2)
    3.5

    >>> round(get_function_max(lambda x, *a: a[0]-a[1]*(x**2)-a[1]*x, 3.0, 2.0), 2)
    3.5
    """
    def func(x, *arg):
        return -f(x, *arg)
    return f(opt.fmin(func, 0, args=args, disp=False)[0], *args)
```