# Golden-section search in multiple dimensions

Tags: algorithm, max

I have a unimodal function f_1:(0,1) -> (0,1) without explicit expression and I look for it's maximum. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146924/finding-the-maximum-of-a-function) that suggest using the golden section algorithm, which perfectly fits what I needed.

But what if now I need to do the same thing for  f_2 : (0,1)x(0,1) -> (0,1)? My guess it that we can alternate the search on the dimensions: do it on the first, then on the second, then repeat. However, is there a way of doing it which is smarter? Evaluation f(x) takes me about 5 minutes.

Comment: Using gradient information can speed things up, second derivative even more (see newton raphson). So is there a way for you to do automatic differentiation?

Comment: @Unlikus if there is I see no obvious way of doing so. For a little bit of context: f correspond to the average gain of some games of an AI i'm tuning vs a random player. To evaluate f(x) I just play 200 games. From my old discrete mathematics class the only way of doing similar would be to evaluate f(x-e) and f(x+e), is that so? I'm not sure it would be that much faster

Comment: ok then its not really possible to calculate gradients. You don't need f(x-e) and f(x+e), you can do with f(x,y), f(x+e,y) and f(x,y+e) and estimate the direction to go from there. This is definitely better than your two interleaved 1-d searches, because your not restricted to just the x and y direction

Comment: The best thing would probably be a bayesian optimization with an 2d gaussian as prior. This captures your belief, that the function is unimodal. Most implementations use gaussian processes as prior, which can be too general, but worth a try. So you might need a custom implementation which is doable, but requires some math.

Comment: Unimodal doesn't help much. Consider a ridge twisted into a spiral around the peak.  The whole function is unimodal, but there may be many local maxima in any dimension.  I second the suggestion from @Unlikus that you do Bayesian optimization.

Comment: Those wouldn't be two-player zero-sum games, would they?