# How to do optimization when the function has flat regions and "cliffs" （or, like a valley）

Tags: python, matlab, optimization

Let's say there is a function that maps real numbers to real numbers and looks like following: when x goes from low to high, f(x) initially is in a flat plain (around a constant but not necessarily constant, could be bumpy), and then there is a "cliff" and value increases a lot quickly. After it achieves maximum, it drops a little bit and becomes flat again. Suppose I know the objective function has this feature but do not know where the "cliff" starts and ends on domain. How should I find the maximum? Placing the initial value in the flat region will get it stuck quickly, but finding a better initial point (e.g., near the cliff) is challenging (e.g., random sample initial points) especially when the dimension of inputs gets larger.

I tried random sample initial points but this might not be efficient for lager size inputs. Looking for recommendation for algorithm/idea. If there is package in python/R/Matlab it would also be great!

Comment: Look up "particle swarm optimisation (PSO)" or "genetic algorithm (GA)". There are libraries for these in Matlab (optimisation toolbox) and probably in Python. Of you could write your own.

Comment: check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146924/finding-the-maximum-of-a-function

Comment: Random sampling seems the right approach. You can use a random grid for efficiency. This is how PSO starts. Use the best guess as initialization for a normal maximization function.

Comment: Annealing is also often a good bet maximizing non-smooth non-differentiable functions: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.dual_annealing.html